# Build gets stuck at 91% after npm run start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd

All of a sudden this error appeared when I did npm run start.
The project is built with ant-design pro.
The sad part is that it doesn't tell me where the error is.
Could you help me find the error or to fix it.
The build just gets stuck at 91% and then I get the error message.

Here's the error:

```
 build [==================  ] 91%(node:6978) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid string length
    at formatError (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:223:30)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Stats.toJson (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:230:31)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:68:44)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at Compiler.emitAssets (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:354:8)
    at onCompiled (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:58:19)
    at applyPluginsAsync.err (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:510:14)
    at next (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5)
    at next (/home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at /home/teks/trips/may26th/smarttrips_react/node_modules/hard-source-webpack-plugin/index.js:2075:7
    at <anonymous>
(node:6978) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6978) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

EDIT : I also updated my npm to ver 6 but still get the same error message. please advise.

Comment: ok. let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had been searching and now I found an issue posted which helped me out.
Basically, adding this code to my package.json is what helped me out.

```
"start": "HARD_SOURCE=none npm run _start", "_start": "cross-env ESLINT=none roadhog dev",
```

I couldnt understand much more of why as it was written in chinese,
Anyways, here's the link to the github issue as it may help some of you understand what was wrong.
[antdesign github issue fixed here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/1520)

Answer (score 0):

It might be coz the **localhost** is not defined with the *required syntax* in the **"hosts"** file of the system.
The file can be located @:

***linux***

`etc/hosts`

**Windows**

`c:\ **Windows** \System32\Drivers\ **etc** \ **hosts**`

i.e. file has some wrong input.

So, Try replacing everything in that file with the text below as this is the default text that was always there in *hosts* file when it worked fine:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1             localhost

fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```